# How to upload another version of app to itunesconnect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have submitted my first version to appStore but there was some error and so apple team refused that version. Now I have correct my mistakes and want to upload another build version, but when I archived my app and when I want to validate and upload new version it deduces error that says that I already have the version in ItunesConnect and how to delete that version and replace with the new version ?

Comment: you need to change build number in target .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your project - General - Identify
   There is your app info. Such as Display Name, Bundle identifier, Version, Build
2. Change your app's Build Number. In my app, Version is 1.0.2 but Build is 1.0.2.01 so if you want to change your app version and upload it just change the last number of Build number. 1.0.2.01  , 1.0.2.02 , 1.0.2.03 like this.
3. If you upload final app version then the version of app info will be shown just 1.0.2  (not 1.0.2.01, 1.0.2,02....)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77dH2.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change build number in project target setting.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) Change the version and build number from Xcode.

2) Archive and upload to Appstore.

3) Open iTunes Connect

in your case only change the build number and you will find your build in build section when you click on + icon

4) Click + Version or Platform from the left pane.

Follow this :-

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html